# Why the win_check function is not working properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new and I have created a tic tac toe game in python I worked out the logic but the code is not behaving as expected I have tried to debug it but can't find the bug.

I am new to python and taking course on udemy in the course I was asked to write a tic tac toe game by myself at first. I have figured out a not so good logic but it will do the job. I just can't figure out why win_check function is not working properly. Is it win_check function or something  else? What are some suggestion for improving my code? 
Sorry for not giving comments in code I just wanted to complete it first and run it successfully.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jul 27 20:11:38 2019

@author: sandeep
"""

from os import name,system
from time import sleep
from random import randint



def game_board(turns):
    print(turns[6],"|",turns[7],"|",turns[8])
    print("--|---|---")
    print(turns[3],"|",turns[4],"|",turns[5])
    print("--|---|---")
    print(turns[0],"|",turns[1],"|",turns[2])



def check_input(player1,player2):
    if (player1 == 'X' or player1 == 'O') and (player2 == 'X' or player2 == 'O'):
        return True
    else:
        print("Please choose between X and O")
        global initial_player_value
        initial_player_value = take_input()
        return False






def take_input():
    player1 = input("Do you want 'X' or 'O'?\n")
    if player1 == 'X':
        player2 = 'O'
    else:
        player2 = 'X'
    return (player1,player2)







def clear():
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')
    else:
        _ = system('clear')





def player_turn(initial_player_value0,initial_player_value1):
    clear()
    global turns
    game_board(turns)
    print(f"Player {initial_player_value0} turn")
    print("Enter position")
    player1_input =input()
    turns.pop(int(player1_input)-1)
    turns.insert(int(player1_input)-1,initial_player_value0)
    clear()
    game_board(turns)

    print(f"Player {initial_player_value1} turn")
    print("Enter position")
    player2_input = input()
    turns.pop(int(player2_input)-1)
    turns.insert(int(player2_input)-1,initial_player_value1)
    clear()
    game_board(turns)



def win_check(check,initial_player_value3,initial_player_value4):

   # print(check)

    global game_status
    if initial_player_value3 == 'X':
        if ((['X','X','X'] == check[:3]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[3:6]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[6:])):
            game_status = "Player X wins"
        elif ((['X','X','X'] == check[::3]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[1::3]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[2::3])):
            game_status = "Player X wins"
        elif ((['X','X','X'] == check[::4]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[2:7:2])):
            game_status = "Player X wins"
        else:
            game_status = "_"

    else:
        if ((['O','O','O'] == check[:3]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[3:6]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[6:])):
            game_status = "Player O wins"
        elif ((['O','O','O'] == check[::3]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[1::3]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[2::3])):
            game_status = "Player O wins"
        elif ((['O','O','O'] == check[::4]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[2:7:2])):
            game_status = "Player O wins"
        else:
            game_status = "_"

    if initial_player_value4 == 'O':
        if ((['O','O','O'] == check[:3]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[3:6]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[6:])):
            game_status = "Player O wins"
        elif ((['O','O','O'] == check[::3]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[1::3]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[2::3])):
            game_status = "Player O wins"
        elif ((['O','O','O'] == check[::4]) or (['O','O','O'] == check[2:7:2])):
            game_status = "Player O wins"
        else:
            game_status = "_"

    else :
        if ((['X','X','X'] == check[:3]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[3:6]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[6:])):
            game_status = "Player X wins"
        elif ((['X','X','X'] == check[::3]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[1::3]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[2::3])):
            game_status = "Player X wins"
        elif ((['X','X','X'] == check[::4]) or (['X','X','X'] == check[2:7:2])):
            game_status = "Player X wins"
        else:
            game_status = "_"
    draw_check = ''.join(str(x) for x in check)
    print(draw_check)
    #sleep(5)
    if draw_check.isalpha():
        game_status ="Game draws"

    else:
        game_status= "_"









#def welcome():
print("Welcome to the tic tac toe game\n")
initial_player_value = take_input()
check = check_input(initial_player_value[0],initial_player_value[1])
while check is False:
    check = check_input(initial_player_value[0],initial_player_value[1])
print(f"Player 1 is {initial_player_value[0]} and Player 2 is {initial_player_value[1]}\nLet's start the game" )

turns = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sleep(2)
clear()
game_board(turns)
game_status = '_'
decide_first = randint(1,2)
replay = 'yes'



while replay == "yes":
    #global game_status
    if decide_first == 1:
        player_turn(initial_player_value[0],initial_player_value[1])
        game_board(turns)
        win_check(turns,initial_player_value[0],initial_player_value[1])
    else:
        player_turn(initial_player_value[1],initial_player_value[0])
        game_board(turns)
        win_check(turns,initial_player_value[0],initial_player_value[1])

    #win_check(turns,tuple(initial_player_value))    
    if game_status != '_':
        print(game_status)
        replay = input("Do you want to play again?\n")
        turns = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

No error while running the code.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you're facing is in win_check.
win_check does the following steps:

1. it checks if the first player wins, and sets the variable game_status to either `"Player X wins"`, or `"Player Y wins"`, or `"_"`
2. it checks if the second player wins, and sets the variable game_status to either `"Player X wins"`, or `"Player Y wins"`, or `"_"`
3. it checks if the a draw happens and sets the variable game_status to either `"game draws`" or `"_"`

after each step it deletes the result of the last step.

It would be more readable and functionally correct if you use a single `if` en `elif` chain to manage the control flow.
I would also move the checking whether a player has won to its own function called `has_won`, this would improve readability and reduce code duplication.

```
def win_check(board, player_1, player_2):
    global game_status
    if has_won(board, player_1):
        game_status = "Player " + player_1 + " has won"
    elif has_won(board, player_2):
        game_status = "Player " + player_2 + " has won"
    elif is_draw(board):
        game_status = "Game draws"
    else:
        game_status = "_"
```